# How to cancel multiple alarms with duplicate PendingIntent at once?

Tags: android, duplicates, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am setting multiple alarms which will have the exact same `PendingIntent` object, but their time of going off is different.  If I cancel one alarm by providing the same `Intent` object to `PendingIntent`, and pass this to `AlarmManager.cancel()`, will it cancel all the alarms (i.e. with different starting times) or will it exhibit some other behavior?

Here is the code:

```
while(size != 0)
{
    timeToSet = getNewTime(); //gets calendar object
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("uniqueid", uuid);
    intent.putExtra("vibrate", myalarm.getVibrate());
    intent.putExtra("important", myalarm.getImportant());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(),      
                                       0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToSet.getTimeInMillis(), 604800000, pendingIntent);

    size--;
}
```

So the Intent object is same for all the alarms, but the time is different.
Now when I cancel these alarms:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("uniqueid", uuid);
intent.putExtra("vibrate", myalarm.getVibrate());
intent.putExtra("important", myalarm.getImportant());
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Will all the alarms get cancelled? That is what I want it to do. I could use a different `requestCode` in every `PendingIntent`, but it will be better if all of them get cancelled as I dont want to maintain and store these extra `requestCodes`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a predefined amount of alarms you can set a unique `requestCode` (second parameter of `getBroadcast`) for each alarm. But I'm not sure if that works for you. If you don't specify a `requestCode` all alarms will be seen as equal by `filterEquals`and therefore all alarms will be canceled.

Comment: This is what I want to do, cancel all the alarms together. Thank you!